# How to concatenate features with LSTM?

Tags: keras

I am new to LSTM. I have to concatenate word to integer feature and other feature which is shown as below.

My task is sentence classification

`feature_1` = 1) `[[16,27,31,42], [0,0,14,21], [0,0,0,72], [0,15,34,31]]`. -> this is a sentence

2. `[[12,56,12,34], [0,1,22,5], [23,56,2,1], [0,0,0,23]]` -> this is a sentence

This feature is word to integer i.e., each word is associated with an integer.

The next feature is a feature for each sentence.

feature_2 is below.

1. -> `[1,2,0,0,1,0,3,4]`  (for 1st sentence)
2. -> `[3,4,2,1,3,4,5,7]`  (for 2nd sentence)

I have the following code which gives an error.

```
mdl_input1 = Input(shape=(max_review_length,)) [max_review_length is the padded sequence i.e., len(x_train[0])  x_train is feature_1]   

x = LSTM(100, activation='tanh')(mdl_input1)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)


mdl_input2 = Input(shape=(30,))  #(30 is length of x_train2[0] i.e., feature_2[0]'s length)

concat = concatenate([x, mdl_input2])

x = Dense(10)(x)
x = Dense(20)(x)
output = Dense(2)(x)

model = Model([mdl_input1, mdl_input2], output)

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])



model.fit([x_train, x_train2], y_train)
```

Note:- `len(x_train[i])` is equal to `len(x_train[j])` for all `i` and `j` as it is padded.

Similar case with `x_train2` as is a feature corresponding to each sentence.

The error is :- `Error when checking input: expected input_5 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (217767, 50)`

But this is wrong I feel. I would like to know the python code for this. Also the code to predict the the model.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example that you can use in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/).

Looking at this example, it seems like you have the right function in use, so it maybe helpful, to help if you could provide the full stack trace of the error. It is hard to tell where this error is occurring in the code from what you provided.